# Language Support for Java Visual studio code extension intellisense not enabling

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I still haven't figured out how to get any features of popular Language support for Java -extension by Red hat working in an existing project.

The first problem I encountered was that the project requires Java 8 to run but then again Language support for Java -extension requires Java 11 at minimum. Extension clearly indicated this issue with a popup warning and the warnings disappeared by adding the following to my user settings:

> ```
> "java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64",
>     "java.configuration.runtimes": [
>    
>       {
>         "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
>         "path": "/home/test/jdk1.8.0_231_oracle",
>         "default": true
>       },
>       {
>         "name": "JavaSE-11",
>         "path": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64",
>       }
>     ]
> ```

I don't have workspace settings and I don't see anything that should override or affect this.

Anyway, this wasn't at least the full solution to my problem as there is still no sign of Intellisense if I open any Java file. I have surely restarted my machine, but no luck.

I went further to test this issue to create a new dummy project and there I was able to get IntelliSense working just by adding the first Java file to the project. At the moment of adding that first Java file, Visual studio code created automatically content into the Java projects -tab on the left side of the screen. Also, Java text appeared on the bottom right panel next to a few other icons. I guess that this is another mandatory thing to get intellisense working.

Unfortotunetley in my real project, even though it contains a huge amount of Java files, the Java projects -tab remains empty. Even if I would try the same trick I did in my dummy project - adding a new Java file to root - does not activate anything in Java projects -tab. Thus also no sign of running Java-version on the bottom right panel. I just can't seem to find a way to tell Visual studio that "hey, my project is a Java project" even it contains loads of java files and extension is not smart enough to do it automatically or it tries to do some extremely fancy stuff and fails on some niche thing preventing even the most simplest java developement support. The Java settings are the same no matter if I open my dummy project or real project as none of those contain workspace settings and java settings should be only in user settings and I believe user settings are shared among all projects.

In my real project, Visual Studio is at least able to understand that the project is a Maven project, and the Maven tab just under the Java projects -tab contains multiple rows.

I understood that Language Support for Java -extension should start a Java language server. I figured out that it is possible to somehow monitor this server by pressing the thumb icon on bottom right panel. In my real project, the thumb is up at least. The logs are not that informative but it seems like the build has been successful. There is one problem though in the Problems tab - could it be the reason why nothing is working:

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for test: test:test
> failed to transfer from XXX during a previous attempt. Original error:
> Could not transfer xxx test:test from/to XXX: Access denied to XXX.
> Error code 401, Unauthorized and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong
> local POM

After further investigations this pom issue has become my main candidate for the reason behind IntelliSense does not work in any Java files. But how to fix this pom issue is still unclear. There should be no access rights problems loading the super pom as anyway, I've been able to successfully build this project and launch it locally and it sill work - i guess it could not get up without being able to load the super pom. So why it breaks here just when it is needed to tell Visual studio my project really is a java project.

Comment: Maven project needs to install **Maven for Java** to support. Besides, we often recommend users to install [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack), one of the extensions called Visual Studio IntelliCode has features like AI-assisted development and Completion list ranked by AI. You may try them. For your reference: [Maven in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-build#_maven).

Comment: I just checked and i have both Maven for java and Extension pack for java installed. Seems to me that the package i talked about in this topic - the language support for java -extension - is a subpackage of this extension pack for java -extension. Anyway, visual studio cant still recognize any java files as java files and does not give any support for java developement.

Comment: Network issue or jdk docs missed. this two are possible reasons, so you may change network or install another jdk version then check if intellisense works.

Comment: I doubt network or jdk docs would be causing this. F.e. maven clean install works like a charm and all pom dependencies are downloaded without network issues. Everything seems to be working, but as soon as I enable the Language support for Java -extension, it starts to complaing pom issues. I'm afraid the problem might be related to one other thread I found, where at least part of the solution was adding this param to settings.json: "java.configuration.maven.userSettings": "/home/test/maven/settings.xml" Unfortunately, with my luck, this just leads to a new error complaining project outofdate.

Comment: I guess I still need to test same with java.configuration.maven.userSettings at least...

Comment: It's not related to maven configuration like you see the question now is the basic java language server and its intellisense. please install another jdk by the command **Java: Install New JDK**, then set the new jdk as `java.home`, see if intellisense appears.

Comment: I haven't had much time to struggle with visual studio Java support latey, but accidentally I realized in one other project Java Intellisense was working. And I haven't updated the Java versions at any point between this time. So I'm afraid it's not a problem with the Java version, but related to this only error message I'm receiving: "Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for test: ...." that I copy pasted in the original question in its full form.